# PBDOM : Exporting to XML writing to Document

Tags: xml, powerbuilder

Building a XML Document in Memory, using PBDOM

Inspecting the generated file, I see, it has sudden terminated and there are missing lines:

```
<device>
    <guid>4aa3d7c5-09bc-4e40-8603-e65157d9e32d</guid>
    <devicenumber>00082078</devicenumber>
<device>
```

It only happens on larger files. Is there a buffer size which has to be enlarged?

Thank you
Stephan

Comment: PBDOM does work for building/processing xml, but it is not the best solution for big files. PB is very slow in string processing. That said, a PB string is limited to 2GB. For my curiosity, how is the size of your big files?

Comment: It is much more lower than 2 GB, but it ends suddenly. This File is only 32 KB when it ends.

Comment: Normally it starts like this:    <device>
    <guid>5223eff4-ee4b-4334-8401-a041a4efc232</guid>
    <devicenumber>00071175</devicenumber>
    <devicekind>dk-hca</devicekind>
    <manufacturer>mxs</manufacturer> ....

Comment: The last line ends in a Tag <device>
    <guid>4aa3d7c5-09bc-4e40-8603-e65157d9e32d</guid>
    <devicenumber>00082078</devicenumber>
    <dev
This last Tag should be <devicekind> dk-hca</devicekind> but the file ends with <dev    All lines are written into the buffers without error. It happens in the doc.SaveDocument(ps_file) Command. doc is a pbdom_document.

Comment: You did not shown any code on the document making. I can only make guess. The document is truncated but still well-formed. Maybe you are reusing a `PBDOM_ELEMENT` by mistake at some point in your code. Are you sure this is a size problem with the very same code, or a case where you are following a different code path?

Comment: BTW, for your additional info, instead of putting in comment, you could edit your question to put them in a more readable form.